# Restore master from upstream repo into fork

Tags: git, github, rebase, git-fork, upstream-branch

I accidentally deleted the master branch from my fork.
Now I want to reset master in my fork to be as the upstream master.

How do I do this?

Comment: Select the last commit, and create a branch "master" on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new master branch by tracking upstream master branch and force push the newly created master branch to you forked repo. The command would be like below,

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git checkout -b master --track upstream/master
$ git push <forked-repo-origin> master -f
```

Please try it out and let me know if you need more.

Comment: Will this touch all the other branches in my origin repo?

Comment: No, it will just update the master branch of your forked repo.

Comment: That worked. For the future, is there a way to perform this from within VS? perhaps with VS extension for GitHub?